# What certificate and provisioning profile to use to build ios version for VS App Center

Tags: ios, visual-studio-app-center

What certificate to use to build ios version for [VS App Center](http://appcenter.ms)? I used distribution certificate with App store distribution provisioning profile, App center accepted the file, but installation on the device failed. Should it be Add-hoc provisioning profile instead? Or even developer's versions?

Answer (score 2):

Apparantely, App store distribution provisioning profile works. The issue was with provisioning the device in App center. Though I added it during first installation, it did not work for some reasons. Recompiled the app and uploaded a new version - and it was successfully installed.

Comment: But if i want to distribute application publicly means without adding UDIDs on Apple Developer Portal, which profile should i upload then?

Comment: I upload dev profile or ad-hoc profile then app is only installing on those devices which are bundled into that profile. But when i upload distribution profile, app is not installing at all even on registered devices. I want to distribute my application publicly. So that anyone can install it without adding their device on Apple Developer Portal.